# Firefox paste event not being triggered with CTRL+V with angular 4 Input field

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to make an Input field for a given type of code which has to be masked on the screen. **The solution is working perfectly in Chrome** but in Firefox, this implementation is making the paste event not to be fired when the user type CTRL+V. It works however if Right Click -> paste. The code for the field is:

```
<input 
matInput 
placeholder="{{'person.cpf' | translate}}" 
maxlength="14"
formControlName="cpf" 
[(ngModel)]="personData.cpf" 
required 
(paste)="teste()"
ngf-enable-firefox-paste="true"
[class.has-error]="formInformation.controls['cpf'].touched"
[mask]="'000.000.000-00'">
```

I already tried adding the `ngf-enable-firefox-paste="true"` directive, didn't solved. I added this test `(paste)="teste()"` and noticed that the function `teste` is called in chrome with CTRL+V but not in Firefox. If I remove the directive `[mask]="'000.000.000-00'"` then the CTRL+V works normally but then I lost the mask. What can be causing this?

Comment: What does mask do?

Comment: formats the content to a standard Brazilian CPF like 123.456.789-12

Comment: Did you use `preventDefault` by any chance?

Comment: no, I just use the `[mask]` directive and if I remove it, the CTRL+V works normally. The thing is, the event `(paste)` is not even being raised on firefox